# How to identify this node using Xpath using Google Sheets IMPORTXML()

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use `IMPORTXML()` in my Google Sheet to extract data from a particular node [at this URL](https://www.auction.com/residential/VA/active_lt/auction_date_order,resi_sort_v2_st/y_nbs/bank-owned,newly-foreclosed,foreclosures_at/). The node I'm targeting looks like the following.

```
<div data-elm-id="asset_2820933_address" class="styles__address-container--2l39p styles__u-mr-1--3qZyj">
  <h4 data-elm-id="asset_2820933_address_content_1" class="styles__asset-font-big--vQU7K">
    246 LOWER VIEW ROAD
  </h4>
  <label data-elm-id="asset_2820933_address_content_2" class="styles__asset-font-small--2JgrX">
    Strasburg, VA 22657, Warren County
  </label>
</div>
```

My goal is to extract the two strings representing the address.

> 246 LOWER VIEW ROAD
>   Strasburg, VA 22657, Warren County

However, when I do so, I get an error.

My Xpaths are as follows:

```
//h4[starts-with(@class,"styles__asset-font-big")]
//label[starts-with(@class,"styles__asset-font-small")]
```

So my full Google Sheets formula looks like this:

> IMPORTXML("https://www.auction.com/residential/VA/active_lt/auction_date_order,resi_sort_v2_st/y_nbs/bank-owned,newly-foreclosed,foreclosures_at/", '//h4[starts-with(@class,"styles__asset-font-big")] | //label[starts-with(@class,"styles__asset-font-small")]')

Is this even possible? Or is scraping that site being blocked some how? If it's possible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that the page is loaded by Javascript. By this, unfortunately, the HTML data cannot be directly retrieved with IMPORTXML and Google Apps Script. I thought that if API for retrieving the values is prepared at the site, the values might be able to be retrieved. But I couldn't find it. I apologize for these situations.

Comment: @Tanaike: So Google Apps Script does not support AJAX, promises or `async/await`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, when Google Apps Script is used at only the server side, the latest Javascript cannot be used. In this case, the version of Javascript can be seen at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features). But when a dialog and Web Apps is opened by Google Apps Script, the latest Javascript can be used because the Javascript is run at the browser of the client side. If this is not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.